# Making my Toast component available to child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to find a way to have my 3rd party Toast component, available in child components. In my example, I have it working with direct children of the `app.js`. But I'm not sure how to get any grand children to make use of it.

I have a repo at https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning if that helps. (Never done open source stuff, so not sure if you can edit)

I am trying to use this component:
(https://github.com/jossmac/react-toast-notifications)

In my app.js importing the packages, and then loading the child components with:

`<Route exact path="/accounts" component={withToastManager(Accounts)} />`

Then (somehow) my child component has access to the toastManager:

`const { toastManager } = this.props;`

And I can show toast notifications with:

```
toastManager.add('Login Success', {
                appearance: 'success',
                autoDismiss: true,
                pauseOnHover: false,
              });
```

However, for my NavBar... I have a bit of a structure.

Header is my component that I call from app.js... Header it's self doesn't use the Toast. But it has a child called NavBar, which has a Logout button. When I click Logout, I want to show toast.

But it has no idea what ToastManager is.

I am trying this:

```
handleLogout() {
  const { toastManager } = this.props;
  const {pathname} = this.props.location;
  this.context.changeAuthenticated(false);
  if(pathname !== "/") {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
  toastManager.add('You\re now logged out', {
    appearance: 'success',
    autoDismiss: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
  });

}
```

But toastManager is not an item available to me.

Is there a way I can make any component that will use Toast notifications, be aware of them? I think I need to wrap my navbar in `withToastManager`, but then all my siblings need to have a reference to ToastManager.

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: Are you passing the toastManager as props from header (parent) component to Navbar (child)?
Because I don't see you are passing the props in your code.

Comment: You should really read up on Higher Order Components, it will explain how `withToastManager` is wrapping your Accounts component and adding more props, like the toast manager. Just wrap your Navbar component's export with the same `withToastManager` HOC.

Comment: @SmSrikanth - Someone advised to pass the props from Header to Hanvbar, so the code now has that, and it works. But I'm not sure that is right. I feel I should not have to pass props from parent to child, down the chain. But maybe it;'s right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [react's Higher Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) documentation, but basically you want to wrap each component individually that needs the `withToastManager` prop(s) injected.

In your `navbar.js` file you'll want to import the `withToastManager` from 'react-toast-notifications', and wrap the export:

```
import { toastManager } from 'react-toast-notifications';

...

export default withToastManager(
  withRouter(Navbar)
);
```

This will add the toast manager as a prop that you can access in the component via `this.props.toastManager`.

A side note, typically you'll also want to use this same pattern of wrapping the export of components that need props/functionality that the HOCs provide instead of elsewhere in the app, like in your router in app.js.